# Expanding hiding elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So my question is, how to create an expandable tree while iterating through an array in AngularJS. I mean I could get it work, the problem that they expanded/closed together.

my html:

```
[...]
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="item-title" ng-click="setState()">{{ item.title }}</div>
    <div class="item-container" show-me="isShown">
         {{ item.content }}
    </div>
</div>
```

my js:

```
[...]
//in controller:

$scope.isshown = false;
$scope.setState = function() {
    $scope.isshown = !$scope.isshown;
};
[...]
.directive("showMe", function($animate) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.showMe, function(newVal) {
            if(newVal) {
                $animate.addClass(element, 'show');             
            } else {
                $animate.removeClass(element,'show');
            }
        });
    };
});
```

so this basicly opens every items. I was looking for a solution for 3 days now and I really dont want to make exceptionally long jquery thingies with $(div#blabla)-s. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your directive to use an isolate scope:

```
.directive("showMe", function($animate) {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.showMe = false;
            scope.$watch('showMe', function(newVal) {
                if(newVal) {
                    $animate.addClass(element, 'show');             
                } else {
                    $animate.removeClass(element,'show');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

-- Edit to answer to the question in the comments below --

To access the isolate scope from outside the directive you can use the angular element. Use JavaScript to get the node using document.getElementById, document.getElementsByClassName, document.querySelector, etc. Once you have the element you want do the following.

```
var node = document.getElementById('MyElement');
var el = angular.element(node);
var scope = el.scope();
scope.showMe = false;
```

Alternatively you can just create a listener to control its value inside of your directive like this:

```
.directive("showMe", function($animate) {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.showMe = false;

            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.showMe = !scope.showMe;
                });
            });

            scope.$watch('showMe', function(newVal) {
                if(newVal) {
                    $animate.addClass(element, 'show');             
                } else {
                    $animate.removeClass(element,'show');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: How would you modify the isolated scope's `showMe` from outside of the directive so you can control its state?

Comment: Good question, I'll modify the answer to show that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="item-title" ng-click="item.isShown = !item.isShown">{{ item.title }}</div>
    <div class="item-container" ng-show="item.isShown">
         {{ item.content }}
    </div>
</div>
```

You do not need any extra javaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

The scope is shared across all the instances of your directive, so every `showMe` checks the same `isshown` variable. An easy solution would be to modify your code like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="item-title" ng-click="setState(item)">{{ item.title }}</div>
    <div class="item-container" show-me="isShown(item)">
         {{ item.content }}
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.setState = function(item) {
    item.isshown = !item.isshown;
};
$scope.isShown = function(item) {
    return item.isshown;
};
```

Here you use the item as a data source as well as an object holding the state of the "openness". The directive's watch will call the isShown function in your controller, where you would extract the state for that item. Optionally you could use an array somewhere else where each shown item is stored (and of course removed on hide), and the isShown just checks if the array has that item in it.